# id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block error

Tags: android, kotlin

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    kotlin("android.extensions")
 

        }
```

I am aware kotlin-android-extensions is deprecated now and this is the link to figure it out (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation). I am just confused to what I update. I have a button that should show a message when the user does not enter their name through Toast.makeText , however this does not work and I believe it is due to my plugins etc. I have tried the view binding = true and kotlin("kotlin-extentions") and I get this error: only id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

Comment: Are you wanting to ignore the deprecation and use `kotlin-android-extensions` anyway? Or do you want to know what is recommended to do instead?

Comment: If I can ignore the deprecation that would be nice and use that extension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `kotlin("android.extensions")` with `id 'kotlin-android-extensions'`.

Comment: I was using id 'kotlin-android-extensions' before , what I did now was create a new AVD and it worked. The AVD I was using before was not updating.

Comment: Use this format.


plugins {
  id("kotlin-kapt")
  id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")          
}